# How to get the max value of date column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame like below:-

```
df =
   Name   Date_1     Date_2     Roll.no
   kiram  22-01-2020 23-01-2020  20
   krish  24-02-2020 05-01-2020  25
   verm   09-01-2020 25-02-2020  24
   kirn   14-12-2019 25-01-2021  56
```

Now I want to get the `max` value for date columns. Above is just an example for understanding, I can make out which date column and find the `max` value in it but I want to do it automatically.
So, to achieve that I have used `if condition` but in spark date, `d-type` is the string itself so I have used try and except to get it but when I implement it I get nothing like below:-

```
for col in df:
  try:
    if dict(df.dtypes)[col]== 'string':
      min, max = df.select(min(col), max(col)).first()
      print(max)
  except:
    print(col, 'NA')
```

Output:-

```
Column<'Name'> NA
Column<'Date_1'> NA
Column<'Date_2'> NA
```

Expected output:-

```
Column<'Name'> NA
24-02-2020 
25-01-2021
```

Is there any better way to find the date column and find its max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you used `try/except`. The if-statement should be enough. Also you need to use the Spark SQL min/max instead of those in Python. Avoid naming your variables as min/max, which overrides default functions.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for col in df.columns:
    if dict(df.dtypes)[col]== 'string':
        minval, maxval = df.select(F.min(col), F.max(col)).first()
        print(maxval)
    else:      
        print(col, 'NA')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to do for column type which has dates but not for column Name. As both falls into the same d-type, I have used try and except. But realised now that min and max values can also give results for columns like 'Name'. Any better way to find the d- type of date as a date but not as a string?

Comment: One question, one answer. If you have a new question, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, thanks! @data.is.world

Comment: Yes, can please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884797/is-it-possible-to-find-which-column-is-date-using-d-type-from-spark-data-frame