# Is it possible to find which column is date using d-type from spark data frame (pyspark)?

Tags: string, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dtype

I have a data frame:-

```
df =
   Name   Date_1     Date_2     Roll.no
   kiram  22-01-2020 23-01-2020  20
   krish  24-02-2020 05-01-2020  25
   verm   09-01-2020 25-02-2020  24
   kirn   14-12-2019 25-01-2021  56
```

Now I want to find the date column using `d-types.` As we know that in pyspark date are treated as `strings`, how do we describe the date column d-type as `date` type but not `string`?
This is because I want to apply some function only on date columns. Is there any way to find which column falls into d-type '`Date`'?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df.printSchema()
```

it should say if its a timestamp or date

or you can use to_date() to convert to date format

```
to_date("date").alias("date")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use something like this below based on the use case. In example below converting all date and timestamp columns to string ..

```
        for d_type in df.dtypes:
            if d_type[1] in ('timestamp','date'):
                df = df.withColumn(d_type[0], df[d_type[0]].cast('STRING'))
```